# cordova ios app builds - runs - then crashes after adding plugin name/value in config.xml

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, plugins

My iOS Cordova app crashes whenever I add my plugin name/value mapping in config.xml. The app builds successfully and breaks pointing to the this main function,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool{
   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); -breaks at this point
   return retVal;
   }
}
```

When I remove the two lines from my config.xml below:

```
<plugin name="ModuleHandler" value"ModuleHandlerPlugin" />
<plugin name="ExtractZipFilePlugin" value"ExtractZipFilePlugin" />
```

The app builds and runs without perfectly, but when I added it back it breaks.

Need help on this, thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can point out which out of those 2 plugins that cause the error.

Comment: I deleted one and kept the other still the error continue, reverse it for the other the error still continues.

Comment: Need help on this, any ideas?